# Why does the window disappear instantly after my program finishes running? How can I make it stay around?

Tags: c++, windows, cmd, dev-c++

Why do i have to put `system("pause")` after every program otherwise my programs run but the window just flashes and disappear. And after putting system function it runs and gives an option to press a key to continue. i am using dev c++ 4.9.9.2

Comment: i am using devc++ 4.9.9.2

Comment: Get a better IDE/compiler. Dev-C++ is the scorn of the Windows developer world.

Comment: @rubenvb what do you recommend?

Comment: well, there is a whole bunch of them. [Qt Creator](https://qt-project.org/downloads#qt-creator), [Code::Blocks](http://www.codeblocks.org/downloads), [Eclipse CDT](http://www.eclipse.org/cdt/downloads.php), [Orwell Dev-c++](http://sourceforge.net/projects/orwelldevcpp/) (an up to date compiler is shipped with a renewed Dev-C++), [netbeans](https://netbeans.org/downloads/), and of course [Visual Studio Express for Windows Desktop](http://www.microsoft.com/visualstudio/eng/products/visual-studio-express-for-windows-desktop) (note there is a 2013 Preview if you need more C++11 support)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The program is finished executing. There is nothing else left for it to do.

If you would like, you could replace the `system` call with `std::cin.get();`

Answer (score 1):

I suppose you're using Windows so try this:

Either

- make a shortcut for `cmd.exe` in the folder where your compiled binaries reside (make sure `execute in` [shortcut properties] is the current folder) or
- hit `Windows+R`, type `cmd`, navigate to your executables directory using `cd` command

to obtain a windows command line window that will not close.
Now you can use

> Myexe.exe

an the window will remain open. (You can even clear it to have a fresh empty window by typing `cls`.)

Now you can terminate your program normally.